# can I get the last two digits in my textbox

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the last two digits in my textbox example I have 5.3 in my textbox, How can I get the last one digits(3) and multiply to 60.

Result 5.3 * 60 = 18    or      .3 * 60 = 18

Comment: Do you allways want the value after the dot or can there be multiple numbers after the dot and you really want the last two chars?

Comment: Do you want the last two or the last one? You mention both. Please give some examples of input values and your required output values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last one digit `Convert.ToInt32(Right(Textbox.Text, 1)) * 60` 
Last 2 digits `Convert.ToInt32(Right(Textbox.Text, 2)) * 60`

If you want to take all digits after the "." then

`Convert.ToInt32(Right(Textbox.Text, Textbox.Text.Length - (Textbox.Text.LastIndexOf(".") + 1))) * 60`

Comment: Sir your answer is correct but there is an error. saying me, public read only property right() as Integer has no parameter.

Comment: this is mu real code int textbox...  TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Right(TextBox.Text, 1)) * 60

Comment: Sorry my fault use `Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(TextBox.Text, 1)) * 60`  The compiler is getting confused between the right function you want and the Right property of the form.

Comment: Thankyou Very much but can I have one last question because my code is confusing, this is the full code........................TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToInt3(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(TextBox5.Text, 2)) *60.    My sample is 5.02 So Iwant the .02 *60 rather than 02*60.

Comment: This is your answer 02*60 = 120 but I want isa .02*60 = 1.2. Thanks.

Comment: Then use `Convert.ToDouble(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Textbox.Text, Textbox.Text.Length - (Textbox.Text.LastIndexOf(".")))) * 60` or `Convert.ToDecimal` depending on what you want